# is there any kind of Web storage viable for storage of video game save data?

Tags: html, web-applications, html5-canvas, local-storage, 2d-games

I am currently looking into making a basic video game.
I have programming knowledge in Web technology, but not much in Android so I am most likely going to start by making a Web app on Android.

I haven't used Web storage much in the past, but I do know about local storage and indexed db, which could be considered as a way to store data, but this kind of data seems too easy to delete by mistake because people just generally wipe out Web data once in a while without filtering out important data.

What is the most appropriate way to store Web app game data?

Comment: They are meant to be easy to delete to allow the user to determine what (s)he want to have stored on the computer. You app/game must consider this scenario for any local storage mechanism (should be similar to a first-load scenario). Don't rely solely on local storage, have a server to the rescue and send local data to server you think are important to keep.

Comment: Thank you, yes being able to delete Web data is very important with the amount of cache data, etc. being stored from Web pages.
However some data is more important than others.
I use Chrome and can see "Delete cookies and other site and plug-in data" under clear history which I would usually just delete normally.
It would be nice to have cookies and DB/local store separate :(. Using a server is a great idea, but relying on a server leaves me with some doubts. Anyways, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [storage type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) relies on the characteristics of the data.

- If you want to store small amount of data in key-value standards, you can use [Key-Value Sets](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).
- If you want to store structured data, you should consider to use a [SQLite Database](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).
- You can also use the [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) to keep files.

Since you want an approach more user-proof, I prefer the SQLite approach. Be aware that no method is 100% guaranteed, since rooted phones can grant access to physical data. At least, consider to encrypt sensitive data before sending to the database.

---

You also have the option of hosting a web service that is consumed by the app to gather information. It can be a lot safer, it is easier to be accessed by all instances of the application, but introduces internet dependecy.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.
This will help me a lot with Android development which is what I am looking into.
The initial question does refer more to Web storage(using Web technology like JS) but I can see how using a native option is a lot more stable atm.